# NSXMLParser throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

It is normal to have such issues but I am currently stuck in knowing how it works.
Whenever I use NSXMLparser to parse the URL and store in the database, it gets parsed for the first time but when I parse it again it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS. 
Here is my code:

```
- (void) initParse {

    [super init];

    appleAppDelegate = (appleAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http:example.com/file.xml"] autorelease];

    self.parser1 = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease] ;

    [parser1 setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser1 setDelegate:self];

    [parser1 parse];

}
```

When it reaches the end of the function at "}", it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I am not sure what is wrong since I am releasing my URL and even my parser.
Has any one come across this situation.

Sagos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running with NSZombieEnabled - that will tell you the type of the object which is being accessed after being freed.

Comment: did try that but did not get which object is getting released. got the following error, but could not get which array:                *** -[__NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa2d0900

Comment: Is the object which owns the NSXMLParser getting released?  The array being over released is probably internal to the XML parser.

Comment: In Instruments if you check the memory location it has a list of all alloc and releases or retains and you can track it down this way, it even shows you in the code where it is (if you have source for it that is)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a released object which is exactly your problem, make sure you release at the end and make sure everything you need is still around.

Comment: I did change the autorelease, to release and made sure its released at the time its required.


(void) initParse {

  [super init];

  appleAppDelegate = (appleAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http:example.com/file.xml"];

  self.parser1 = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] ;

  [parser1 setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; [parser1 setDelegate:self];

  [parser1 parse];

  [url release];

}
-(void ) dealloc{ [parser1 release]; }
But still it throws me the same errors.

Sagos

Comment: so it fails with 1 call to initParse or on subsequent calls to initParse?

Comment: subsequent calls on initParse. the first call goes smoothly but on the second call it fails.

Comment: try Andrews advice that makes it much clearer as I have no idea what's happening behind the scenes in your code but I think it might be something with parser1